# How to get formidable entry ID by post ID?

Tags: forms

I have a post created with the "Formidable Pro" plugin. how can i get the entry Id of that post by the post id?

Comment: Probably best to read their docs/support docs? As most of us may have not worked with that plugin.

Comment: If there document had it i wouldn't post a question!

Answer (score 2):

So, after a lot of searching (which is funny, because it's such a basic function which should apear in the documents) i found that:

**what you have to do to get the current post entry id is:**

```
<?php $entry_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT id FROM $frmdb->entries WHERE post_id='". $post->ID ."'"); ?>
```

Comment: Please remember to mark this as the accepted answer. :)